# Embedding of the first Hirzebruch surface in $\mathbb{P}^4$ as a cubic surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry, embeddings

The first Hirzebruch surface (the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at one point) is a projective toric surface that naturally embeds into $\mathbb{P}^4$ as a cubic surface (sometimes called the cubic scroll). As a real algebraic variety, its real part is homeomorphic to a Klein bottle. I am confused about the designation "cubic surface": I (naively) thought that a generic cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^4$ would be the intersection of a cubic hypersurface with a hyperplane. But one cannot embed the Klein bottle in a hyperplane of $\mathbb{RP}^4$ (i.e. in $\mathbb{RP}^3$). What is the (probably quite dumb) misconception on my part ?

Comment: "Cubic surface" here just means of degree 3. It is definitely not contained in a hyperplane.

Comment: To elaborate on abx's comment, degree three means that a general 2-plane intersects it in 3 points.  There are multiple types of cubic surface in 4-space.

Comment: @PhilTosteson , abx, thank you for your comment. There is no relation between the degree of the surface and the degree of the defining equations of the surface then ?

Comment: There is a relation if a variety is a complete intersection, which is not the case for the cubic scroll.